# Passing an optional parameter of an array to webapi endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to write an endpoint to take an optional array of ids as an argument, like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int[] ids = null)
{
    // do something
}
```

Goal being that a call to `/api/myendpoint` will return all records, while a call to `/api/myendpoint?ids=1&ids=2` would return just records 1 and 2.

The issue I'm hitting is the call to `/api/myendpoint` actually initializes an empty array of ids, rather than passing the default null value through.

Any thoughts on how to force it to actually use the default value?

Comment: So why can't you just return all of the records when the array is empty?  Is there a situation in which you want to get an empty array and actually return no results?

Comment: Potentially, yes. The client side that makes this call is being passed the array in question, if that was empty the expected response would be no records. Also a general concern that if the behavior is "pass an array" => "get back those records" that the consistent behavior should be an empty array returning a empty set.

Comment: If you think that the expected results for getting a set of values by ID, when no IDs are provided, should be to provide no results, then why state: "Goal being that a call to /api/myendpoint will return all records, while a call to /api/myendpoint?ids=1&ids=2 would return just records 1 and 2."  If you don't want that endpoint to behave that way, then don't make it behave that way, but you can't say you want it to behave that way and then say that it shouldn't behave that way.  If you want to have two endpoints, one to get all items, and one to get items by ID, then do that.

Comment: I want it to return all results if it's passed a null and to return whatever results match the array if it's passed an array. The client shouldn't have to have the knowledge that passing an empty array returns all records.

Comment: But you just said that if the client hits the endpoint and provides no ID that an empty array, and not `null` is provided, so they don't need to know or care about whether their omission of the `ids` parameter results in your method getting an empty array or `null`, they just know that if they provide no `ids` parameter, they get all of the items, and if they provide ids they get those items.

Comment: @Servy - I think you're misunderstanding. There are two valid user cases that conflict with each other currently: 1) A user calls the endpoint without specifying an array and expects all records or 2) a user passes an empty array and expects no results

Comment: In case 1) the user expects all records returned. In case 2) the user expects no records returned. Right now a call with no id array passed returns no records because it is interpreted as passing an empty array.

Comment: If you want the endpoint to behave differently when called with identical parameters, based on who calls it, then you need to redesign it.  If you want to have one method where providing no idea provides no items, and one where it provides all of them, then you need two methods, one for each desired behavior (i.e. a `GetAllItems` that has no parameter, and a `GetItemsByID` that never returns all items).

Answer (score -1):

This isn’t an exact answer to your question, but it does provide a cleaner and more flexible approach (I tend to avoid optional parameters whenever possible).

You can use `params` To achieve the same behavior:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(
    params int[] ids) { ... }
```

And now, you can call `Get()` for all ids or `Get(1, 2)` for specific ids. To all effects, the usage would be the same and it avoids optional parameters altogether, which IMHO, is an advantage.

Another option is simply implementing two overloads:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Get(
    int[] ids) { ... }

  public async Task<IActionResult> Get() { ... }
```

Anyhow, checking if `ids.Length` is `0` doesn’t seem too onerous.

Comment: What does this get him that the solution in the question doesn't?

Comment: The issue is that ids.length == 0 is a potentially valid use case, where an automated system is generating an empty array and passing it. In that case we'd want to return 0 records, not all of them

Comment: @SamR. Ok, then use the overload solution.

Comment: Just tried this, seems webAPI doesn't like the overloaded routes. I get a 500 without ever hitting the specified endpoint